# String representation of formatters in java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter

Tags: java, datetime, java-8, datetime-format, datetimeoffset

Is there a way to get a string representation of formatters defined statically in `DateTimeFormatter`?

E.g. for `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME` I would like to get something like:

`"uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX"`

I've checked `DateTimeFormatter` source and I coudln't find any methods which gives this info. It internally uses `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` with programmatically set fields, properties etc and does not uses `String`.

When I call `toString()` on a particaular formatter I get e.g.:

```
DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME.toString()
```

gives:

```
ParseCaseSensitive(false)(ParseCaseSensitive(false)(Value(Year,4,10,EXCEEDS_PAD)'-'Value(MonthOfYear,2)'-'Value(DayOfMonth,2))'T'(Value(HourOfDay,2)':'Value(MinuteOfHour,2)[':'Value(SecondOfMinute,2)[Fraction(NanoOfSecond,0,9,DecimalPoint)]]))Offset(+HH:MM:ss,'Z')
```

Comment: There isn’t and for good reasons. As you can already see in the string you got from `toString`, a formatter contains a lot more than just format pattern letters (or what they can represent). So generally a formatter cannot be converted to a format pattern string and back.

Comment: I found the linked duplicate on Google in a single search. Was there a reason you were unable to?

Comment: I might add that since `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME` accepts anything from 0 through 9 decimals on the seconds, no format pattern string will do exactly the same. (`[.SSSSSSSSS][.SSSSSSSS][.SSSSSSS][.SSSSSS][.SSSSS][.SSSS][.SSS][.SS][.S]` would get you close but not exactly there.)